# How to replace character into multiIndex pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a dataset with severals columns containing numbers and I need to remove the ',' thousand separator.

Here is an example: `123,456.15` -> `123456.15`.

I tried to get it done with multi-indexes the following way:

```
toProcess = ['col1','col2','col3']
df[toProcess] = df[toProcess].str.replace(',','')
```

Unfortunately, the error is: `'Dataframe' object has no attributes 'str'`. Dataframe don't have str attributes but Series does.

> How can I achieve this task efficiently ?

Here is a working way iterating over the columns:

```
toProcess = ['col1','col2','col3']
for i, col in enumerate(toProcess):
    df[col] = df[col].str.replace(',','')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df[toProcess] = df[toProcess].replace(',','', regex=True)
```